WidgetKit - complication doesn't sync between watch and iPhone
I'm currently working with complication using widgetkit for watchOS.
When I select complication from Watch app in iPhone, The complication does not show content. In complication gallery, untitled complication is selecting. But when I select complication from watch, it's OK.
image bug
This bug occurs in both real device and simulator. But it happen in some pair.
Example:

watch ultra (os 10.4) pair with iPhone 14 pro (os 17.0): NG
watch ultra (os 10.4) pair with iPhone 14 pro (os 16.1): NG
watch ultra (os 10.0) pair with iPhone 14 pro (os 17.0): OK

I tried create simple project to check this bug. But this bug still occurs. If I create a complication with StaticConfiguration, this bug doesn't occur in this complication. But it still occurs in AppIntentConfiguration's complication.
var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
    AppIntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: ConfigurationAppIntent.self, provider: Provider()) { entry in
        WatchComplicationEntryView(entry: entry)
            .containerBackground(.fill.tertiary, for: .widget)
    }
}

This is sample project: Github
